# Common parent type ifstream and ofstream

Tags: c++, file, c++11, stream

I have a class that contains an `std::ofstream` and an `std::ifstream` (only one can be activated at a time). I would like to overload the `operator()` to return the current active stream. But what is the common base type of `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` to return a common reference ?

Comment: `std::ios`, but you won't really be able to do much with it.

Comment: [This](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I would like to overload the operator() to return the current active stream* This makes absolutely no sense and smells like a design flaw. Why do you want to return that? What should the caller of that operator be able to do with return value? It can neither do input nor output.

I dunno what you really want to do, but perhaps something like this could work for you, though it's dangerous

```
template<typename T> class wrapper
{
  T*const ptr;
  wrapper(T*p) : ptr(p) {}
public:
  bool empty() const { return ptr; }
  operator T& () const
  {
    if(empty()) throw some_exception("trying to use empty wrapper");
    return *ptr;
  }
  friend some_class;
};

class some_class
{
   ifstream _ifstream;
   ofstream _ofstream;
   bool ifstream_is_active;
   bool ofstream_is_active;
public:
   operator wrapper<ifstream> () const
   { wrapper<ifstream>(ifstream_is_active? &_ifstream : 0); }
   operator wrapper<ofstream> () const
   { wrapper<ofstream>(ofstream_is_active? &_ofstream : 0); }
};
```

but this is dangerous, as you are potentially dealing with dangling pointers. You can avoid that by using `shared_ptr` (work this out yourself), but that means that `some_class` has no longer control over the lifetime of these streams.

Comment: Exception specifications are deprecated in C++11 (and ignored by some notable compilers in C++03) – best to omit them. Also, you can't overload functions on return-type only.

Comment: @ildjarn you're quite right. I removed the throw and corrected the other issue (this was a sort of type, I intended type conversion)

Answer (score 1):

Input and output streams are very different types. The only common base class they share is [`std::ios`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios). And that doesn't have much in it besides some error checking stuff.

The two stream types only share the most basic of interfaces. They have little to do with one another, for obvious reasons.

Comment: I think he wants to overload his _own_ class' `operator()` to return some stream, and just wants the common base to know what to make the return type.